# Compute aggregate on other table for each extracted record - performance

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I'm making a query with many joins. 
For one "joined" table there is one to many association and I need to aggregate (SUM) on this one.

I got about 500 to 1000 records extracting at each query execution. It takes about 100 to 200ms (it has many joins). But after adding the aggregate it increases the execution to about 5-6 secs!

I tried 2 solutions (the problem is with the two last columns: **SubchargesTo** and **SubchargesFrom**), both worsened in performance by a large factor:

First:

```
SELECT
            RR.Id,
            Customer.Name AS Customer,
            PrincipalsCustomer.Name AS PrincipalsCustomer,
            EffectiveCarrier.Name AS EffectiveCarrier,
            CAST(CASE RR.isImport WHEN 1 THEN RR.unloadingDateStart ELSE TR.loadingDateStart END AS DATE) AS LoadingUnloadingDate,
            RR.containerNo AS ContainerNumber,
            CASE RR.isImport WHEN 1 THEN PLACEUNLOADING.Name ELSE PlaceLoading.Name END AS LoadingUnloadingPlace,
            Pol.Name AS POL,
            Pod.Name AS POD,
            Commodity.Name AS Commodity,
            RR.Km AS Km,
            RR.pricePerKm AS SalesPricePerKM,
            RR.salesPrice AS SalesPrice,
            RR.purchasePrice AS PurchasePrice
            (SELECT SUM(salesAmount*salesCost) FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges WHERE TruckingTobaccoSurcharges.REPORT = RR.Id) +
            (SELECT SUM(incomeAmount*toSBCIncome) FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2 WHERE TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2.REPORT = RR.Id) as SurchargesTo,
            (SELECT SUM(costAmount*costCost) FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges WHERE TruckingTobaccoSurcharges.REPORT = RR.Id) +
            (SELECT SUM(costAmount*fromCustomerCost) FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2 WHERE TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2.REPORT = RR.Id) as SurchargesFrom
        FROM Report RR
            JOIN TruckingReport TR ON TR.REPORT = RR.ID
            LEFT JOIN Customer ON RR.CUSTOMER = Customer.ID
            LEFT JOIN PrincipalsCustomer ON RR.PRINCIPALSCUSTOMER = PrincipalsCustomer.ID
            LEFT JOIN EffectiveCarrier ON RR.EFFECTIVECARRIER = EffectiveCarrier.ID
            LEFT JOIN PlaceLoading ON TR.PLACELOADING = PlaceLoading.ID
            LEFT JOIN PlaceUnloading ON RR.PLACEUNLOADING = PlaceUnloading.ID
            LEFT JOIN Pol ON TR.POL = Pol.Id
            LEFT JOIN Pod ON TR.POD = Pod.Id
            LEFT JOIN Commodity ON RR.COMMODITY = Commodity.Id
```

The second one:

```
SELECT
            RR.Id,
            Customer.Name AS Customer,
            PrincipalsCustomer.Name AS PrincipalsCustomer,
            EffectiveCarrier.Name AS EffectiveCarrier,
            CAST(CASE RR.isImport WHEN 1 THEN RR.unloadingDateStart ELSE TR.loadingDateStart END AS DATE) AS LoadingUnloadingDate,
            RR.containerNo AS ContainerNumber,
            CASE RR.isImport WHEN 1 THEN PLACEUNLOADING.Name ELSE PlaceLoading.Name END AS LoadingUnloadingPlace,
            Pol.Name AS POL,
            Pod.Name AS POD,
            Commodity.Name AS Commodity,
            RR.Km AS Km,
            RR.pricePerKm AS SalesPricePerKM,
            RR.salesPrice AS SalesPrice,
            RR.purchasePrice AS PurchasePrice,
            SUBCH1.sales + SUBCH2.sales AS SurchargesTo,
            SUBCH1.costs + SUBCH2.costs AS SurchargesFrom
        FROM Report RR
            JOIN TruckingReport TR ON TR.REPORT = RR.ID
            LEFT JOIN Customer ON RR.CUSTOMER = Customer.ID
            LEFT JOIN PrincipalsCustomer ON RR.PRINCIPALSCUSTOMER = PrincipalsCustomer.ID
            LEFT JOIN EffectiveCarrier ON RR.EFFECTIVECARRIER = EffectiveCarrier.ID
            LEFT JOIN PlaceLoading ON TR.PLACELOADING = PlaceLoading.ID
            LEFT JOIN PlaceUnloading ON RR.PLACEUNLOADING = PlaceUnloading.ID
            LEFT JOIN Pol ON TR.POL = Pol.Id
            LEFT JOIN Pod ON TR.POD = Pod.Id
            LEFT JOIN Commodity ON RR.COMMODITY = Commodity.Id
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT REPORT, SUM(salesAmount*salesCost) AS sales, SUM(costAmount*costCost) AS costs
                        FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges SR1 GROUP BY SR1.REPORT
                        )AS SUBCH1 ON SUBCH1.REPORT = RR.ID
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT REPORT, SUM(incomeAmount*toSBCIncome) AS sales, SUM(costAmount*fromCustomerCost) AS costs
                        FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2 SR2 GROUP BY SR2.REPORT
                       )AS SUBCH2 ON SUBCH2.REPORT = RR.ID
```

Is there any faster way to achieve desired result?
Or this many joins can't real make it any faster?

Any help appreciated =]

**EDIT:**

Added index on Report FK on TruckingTobaccoSurcharges table as Nikola Markovinović suggested made it fast again (using solution 1)!
Haven't tried solution 2 though.
Still I'm wondering if my query could be any better, because as other stated I'm not joining but subquerying...

Comment: Version 2 seems fine to me. Are there indexes on Report in both tables?

Comment: Hmm. Im not so in indexes yet, but after expanding "indexes" on the Report table I have "PK_Report (Clustered)".

Comment: `TruckingTobaccoSurcharges` and `TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2` need index on Report column. Use [sp_helpidex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188771%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to check the indexes. `sp_helpindex 'TruckingTobaccoSurcharges'` will show all indexes on this table. If you do not see `Report` as starting field under index_keys you need to add the index: `create index ix_TruckingTobaccoSurcharges_Report on TruckingTobaccoSurcharges (Report)`. The same goes for TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2. If you need speed you have to master indexing.

Comment: As a rule of thumb all foreign keys should be indexed unless foreign table has just a few rows.

Comment: It's blazing fast now! I can measure in miliseconds again.
Thank you very much =] I must get to know indexes for sure =]

Comment: Certainly not the best article, [but something to read on this weekend](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39006/Overview-of-SQL-Server-2005-2008-Table-Indexing-Pa#what_is_index) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to realized that you are not joining!!
Yes, you are joining, because there is LEFT JOIN all over the places, but in fact no, this is not your problem.
You are **subquerying** for retrieve your sum, and this is bad, bad and bad. Subquerying is always slower than joining.

This a subquery, not a join:

```
LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT REPORT, 
           SUM(salesAmount*salesCost) AS sales, 
           SUM(costAmount*costCost) AS costs
    FROM TruckingTobaccoSurcharges SR1 GROUP BY SR1.REPORT
)
```

Because you are subquerying, indexes on REPORT are not use, and so the slowness.

So for your problem, here is what should work: (be aware, real join !!)

```
SELECT
    SUM(s.salesAmount * s.salesCost) + SUM(s2.salesAmount * s2.salesCost) AS SurchargesTo,
    SUM(s.costAmount * s.costCost) + SUM(s2.costAmount * s2.fromCustomerCost) AS SurchargesFrom
FROM Report RR
    LEFT JOIN TruckingTobaccoSurcharges s 
        ON s.REPORT = RR.ID
    LEFT JOIN TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2 ss
        ON s.REPORT = RR.ID
GROUP BY s.REPORT
```

Comment: This version will likely produce cartesian product between `TruckingTobaccoSurcharges` and `TruckingTobaccoSurcharges2` unless one of the tables does not contain matching records. Totals will be off.

Comment: I can't really inject your solution in my query, because I can't have aggregates and table columns in one result. Should I group by all the other columns ?